# AWS presigned URL getting access denied

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm trying to download a file from a pre-signed URL but it seems like something is going wrong somewhere because I am getting access denied. I'm guessing it's the permissions that is incorrect but I don't understand what the incorrect part is.

serverless.yml:

```
  iam:
    role:
      statements:
        - Effect: 'Allow'
          Action:
            - 's3:GetObject'
            - 's3:PutObject'
            - 's3:ListObject'
            - 's3:CreateBucket'
          Resource:
            - "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket/*"
            - "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket"
            - "arn:aws:s3:::*"
```

Creating the pre-signed url in a lambda:

```
def get_presigned_url(key, file):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    key = f'{key}/{file}'
    presigned_url = s3.generate_presigned_url(
        ClientMethod='get_object',
        Params={
            'Bucket': 'my_bucket',
            'Key': key,
        },
    )
    return presigned_url
```

The subfolder in the bucket contains '@' but it gets urlencoded to '%40', could that be a reason?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Answer: the file was in a subfolder that contained @, which was url encoded to %40. Had to rename the subfolder

Answer (score 0):

In Serverless.yml file, Under the provider section, you should write permission like this:

```yaml
 iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - "ssm:GetParameter*"
      Resource: "*"
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - s3:*
      Resource:
        - "*"
```

Hope, this helps

Comment: It doesn't look like it does anything different? Is it the ssm:GetParameter that makes the difference?

Comment: No, The serverless framework will only create role for the statements defined under iamRoleStatements otherwise it won't. The ssm permission is just an example, I copy/pasted it from my code